# Scrolling/Moving around the screen not working in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have made a beta version of an app and am currently testing it out on my iphone se. Earlier, I tested out the simulation on the iphone 6 and everything worked fine, but on the se i am unable to see the all of the app(as in the pictures below). I think this is a result of the screen size, so what do I have to do to make it the same on both? Any help appreciated.

On the 6 it looks like this:
[image]

And on the se it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **auto constraints**. They dynamically change your User Interface, so it look great on every device. Have a look at [this very helpful guide by Apple about all the details](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/), but here I will briefly explain how to apply auto-constraints in Xcode using the `main.storyboard`.

**1) Position your item *roughly* where you want it in the view.**

[image]

**2) Use the controls in the corner to create auto-constraints. These can be changed in many ways, like changing the Multiplier, Constant, Priority etc. This is slightly more advanced, but can be edited in the `Size Inspector` pane later on.**

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

---

**If you have any questions, please ask me!**